# Image caching and using css3 loading spinners - advice needed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website coming along nicely and I now have thumbnail images that I need to put in place.

First thing I want to do is have a loading spinner whilst the image is loading and then once the image has loaded, the spinner no longer shows. I have seen some people place a gif as a background to the image and then then image loads on top. However I want to use a CSS spinner. Here are some examples of CSS Spinners: http://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/

I then want the browser to cache the images once they have been loaded.

I understand that javascript is used for this. Would javascript be used for the spinner to? Are there any websites that give a good overview of this process? Or if anyone here could help it would be much appreciated. This task, I'm sure isn't too hard but I'm really not sure on where to start.

I would produce a jsfiddle example or something but for now I just want to know what to be looking for when going about this.

EDIT: After reading further into this, am I right in saying that the browser caches the images automatically? I'm a little confused as to whether preloading the images is worth it for me or not if that's the case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the image loads, you can turn off the spinner this way (jQuery assumed)

```
<div class="spinner">...</div>


$('.spinner img').on('load', function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('spinner')
})
```

Comment: Thanks. With `$('.spinner img')`, 'img' is contained inside the spinner class I take it? So it would be `<div class="spinner"> <img src="smiley.jpg" alt="Smiley face"</div>` Thus when the 'img' tag loads, the class spinner is removed. The class spinner, is the css3 preloader. Is that right?

Comment: Correct. You will need to build your own .spinner CSS.

Comment: Ok, great. Say I have three images next to each other... I would have three containers, each containing this spinner div and img. What would you say is the best way to have the spinner in the middle of each container? I'm not sure if the spinners would look close together until the images load, therefore causing the containing divs to expand.

Comment: Yes, one for each. The containers should have a min-width and min-height to allow space for the spinner and room for the image to expand the element when it loads.